# Bash script for nested variable prompt for loop

Tags: bash, loops, nested, prompt

I'm trying to make a nested variable prompt for loop in Bash. However, I get the error bad substitution.

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "how many sources?"
read NumSour

for (( i=1; i<=$NumSour; i++ ))
        do
        echo "what is the wavelength of source" ${i}"?"
        read Wave${i}

        for j in Wave${i}
                do
                echo ${Wave${i}} 
                done
        done
```

I want to prompt how many variables, then assign each of those variables with a value. Then print the variables’ values.

Echoing `${j}` gives `Wave1`, `Wave2`, etc. not the values of the variables.

I tried switching to format of the second for loop with the same as the first for loop, but it iterates over the values of the variables.

```
for (( i=1; i<=$NumSour; i++ ))
        do
        echo "what is the wavelength of source" ${i}"?"
        read Wave${i}

        for (( j=Wave1; j<=Wave${i}; j++ ))
                do
                echo ${j}
                done
        done
```

Say `Wave1` is `1` and `Wave2` is `4`, it echos `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`. I need it to just echo `1` and `4`.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: Using dynamic variable names like you're trying to is messy and hard to get right. I'd recommend using an array instead: `read Wave[i]` and `for (( j=Wave[1]; j<=Wave[i]; ...`. This is the sort of thing arrays are for.

Comment: `${Wave${i}}` is not valid bash.